# Fixed size UIView, centered in the view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to have an UIView with `width=480` and `height=640`, centered in the middle of my master view.

I want this to happen both in landscape orientation and portrait orientation, but now if I design it for portrait orientation, when I'm turning the device to landscape, my UIView has `width=640` and `height=480`.

Any solutions for my UIView to keep it's sizes in both orientation types?

Comment: How are you setting the size of the view? Can you show some code where you do that?

Comment: try [yourview centerBothDirections];

Comment: self.myCustomView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlegibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

Comment: right now I've only added it on the storyboard from the objects panel, and i've pinned it's width and height.

Comment: Are you using Autolayout?

Answer (score 3):

you can implement `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (in `UIViewController`) or `layoutSubviews` (in `UIView`) to reposition the view.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    self.myCustomView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 640); // update size
    self.myCustomView.center = self.view.center;           // update center
}
```